# making two share plugin (facebook and twitter) align on the same line (align vertically)

Tags: html, css

I have used twitter and facebook share plugin on mysite as can be seen on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LMvLL/) fiddle. However I am having a hard time making the buttons align vertically. I've tried using margin-top and padding-top however it always stays un-aligned. How do I make the following tweet and facebook share button on the same line looking nicely:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.directory.shopious.com" data-text="some share" data-lang="id" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>


    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.mysite.com" data-width="500" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of **`vertical-align`** property

```
.fb-share-button {
   vertical-align: top;    
}
```

Comment: did you try on the fiddle? it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try vertical-align? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMvLL/4/)

```
.twitter-share-button {
    margin-right: 5%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Without applying `display: table-cell;` is also working.

If you want in the same line as you commented then apply `vertical-align: top;` instead of middle.

Comment: I want both on the same line.. in one line, not stacked like that

Comment: I want twitter and facebook button on 1 single line. right now twitter button is a bit shifted upwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use px to align it more strictl (using @Praveen Jeganathan answer):

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
   vertical-align: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMvLL/7/